# Pandas html to df - commas in numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm newbie in Python. I need to download some tables from Polish language webpages. 
I have problem with commas in numbers because it seems that Pandas delete them?
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.read_html('https://www.gpw.pl/wskazniki', encoding='utf-8', decimal=",")[1]
```

The result in `C/WK` column is `"021"` instead `"0,21"`.
How to download it properly or change to `"0.21"`.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the thousands separator, which also defaults to common.

To read the data and parse it correctly, use:

```
pd.read_html('https://www.gpw.pl/wskazniki',encoding = 'utf-8', decimal=',', thousands='.')[1]
```

The result is: 
[image]

Comment: Be aware that although this displays what you want, the values in the dataframe are currently all stored as strings (with 'x' representing 0, I assume). So if you want to to do any arithmetic on this column, you'll also need to do:

`x['C/Z'] = x['C/Z'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'x' else float(x))`

Comment: @SimonR probably better written as: `pd.to_numeric(x['C/Z'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)`

Comment: `pd.read_html()` function has a `na_values` parameter which allows defining a custom missing value. It's enough to set it o `"x"` and then use `.fillna()`

Comment: @SimonR script works better. However after both dtype of column is float when I try use them only after Simon script everything works properly. After Jon it is still a string during calculations.